# What takes place where in reactjs build system?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

You type `create-react-app` and hit enter and voila! Some magic happens and everything gets set up in a flash. But during the rest of the development process you suffer from lack of knowledge of what really happens behind the scene.

Is there anyone to shed some light on this? What really takes place where? Where does the React compiler lie in the pipeline, and what about babel, and if we use typescript are we replacing babel? When we use `webpack`, how does it combine typescript with react code?

Please tell me where build process starts and where it ends.

Comment: A good starting point would be to [eject](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) the app (just dont commit/push that, since irreversible). Then you can inspect what the configuration looks like; what scripts are used; when and how.

Comment: You probably want to review this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts/config

Comment: yea i know.at worse case i could read through many blog posts illustrating how to setup react app from scratch , but the issue is they don't tell you order of things.

Comment: That's not what's being suggested, *look at the code*. If you have a *specific* question afterward, ask that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you suggest i read through thousands of lines of code to grasp the concept?Then what are docs good for?

Comment: Not thousands, the webpack config you've already been pointed to is about 600 lines. And there are *also* docs to look at: https://webpack.js.org/. But explaining the whole build process isn't in scope for SO.

Comment: could you guide me to that 600 lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

Start with `yarn eject` on your app and you'll see the log which lists the `\config` directory and files; updated npm dependencies; rewritten scripts; and so on. This should be a great start.

```sh
user@desktop /c/GitHub/walktrhough (master)
$ yarn eject
yarn run v1.15.2
$ react-scripts eject
NOTE: Create React App 2+ supports TypeScript, Sass, CSS Modules and more without ejecting: https://reactjs.org/blog/2
018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html

? Are you sure you want to eject? This action is permanent. Yes
Ejecting...

Copying files into C:\GitHub\walktrhough
  Adding \config\env.js to the project
  Adding \config\modules.js to the project
  Adding \config\paths.js to the project
  Adding \config\pnpTs.js to the project
  Adding \config\webpack.config.js to the project
  Adding \config\webpackDevServer.config.js to the project
  Adding \config\jest\cssTransform.js to the project
  Adding \config\jest\fileTransform.js to the project
  Adding \scripts\build.js to the project
  Adding \scripts\start.js to the project
  Adding \scripts\test.js to the project

Updating the dependencies
  Removing react-scripts from dependencies
  Adding @babel/core to dependencies
  Adding @svgr/webpack to dependencies
  Adding @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin to dependencies
@typescript-eslint/parser to dependencies
  Adding babel-eslint to dependencies
  Adding babel-jest to dependencies
  Adding babel-loader to dependencies
  Adding babel-plugin-named-asset-import to dependencies
  Adding babel-preset-react-app to dependencies
  Adding camelcase to dependencies
  Adding case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin to dependencies
  Adding css-loader to dependencies
  Adding dotenv to dependencies
  Adding dotenv-expand to dependencies
  Adding eslint to dependencies
  Adding eslint-config-react-app to dependencies
  Adding eslint-loader to dependencies
  Adding eslint-plugin-flowtype to dependencies
  Adding eslint-plugin-import to dependencies
  Adding eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y to dependencies
  Adding eslint-plugin-react to dependencies
  Adding eslint-plugin-react-hooks to dependencies
  Adding file-loader to dependencies
  Adding fs-extra to dependencies
  Adding html-webpack-plugin to dependencies
  Adding identity-obj-proxy to dependencies
  Adding is-wsl to dependencies
  Adding jest to dependencies
  Adding jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen to dependencies
  Adding jest-resolve to dependencies
  Adding jest-watch-typeahead to dependencies
  Adding mini-css-extract-plugin to dependencies
  Adding optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin to dependencies
  Adding pnp-webpack-plugin to dependencies
  Adding postcss-flexbugs-fixes to dependencies
  Adding postcss-loader to dependencies
  Adding postcss-normalize to dependencies
  Adding postcss-preset-env to dependencies
  Adding postcss-safe-parser to dependencies
  Adding react-app-polyfill to dependencies
  Adding react-dev-utils to dependencies
  Adding resolve to dependencies
  Adding sass-loader to dependencies
  Adding semver to dependencies
  Adding style-loader to dependencies
  Adding terser-webpack-plugin to dependencies
  Adding ts-pnp to dependencies
  Adding url-loader to dependencies
  Adding webpack to dependencies
  Adding webpack-dev-server to dependencies
  Adding webpack-manifest-plugin to dependencies
  Adding workbox-webpack-plugin to dependencies

Updating the scripts
  Replacing "react-scripts start" with "node scripts/start.js"
  Replacing "react-scripts build" with "node scripts/build.js"
  Replacing "react-scripts test" with "node scripts/test.js"

Configuring package.json
  Adding Jest configuration
  Adding Babel preset
  Adding ESLint configuration

Running yarn...
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Ejected successfully!
```

Scan through the `package.json` first. Look at dependencies and scripts (which now are a part of your repository, e.g. `/scripts/start.js` or `/scripts/build.js`).

Both `start.js` and `build.js` use a specific webpack setup each (`webpackDevServer.config.js` and `webpack.config.js`, respectively), so you should inspect them carefully.

Also, scan through the `/config` directory files -- they are often picked up by tools without direct references (via placement conventions -- may look like "magic" as a result).

I understand that 600+ lines long `webpack.config.js` may look intimidating, but it's doable. Prioritize the important things to look first or to ignore completely. There's no golden road unfortunately.